# Kinect dynamic reconfigure does not work

Tags: ros, calibration, kinect, openni.launch, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to follow the tutorial [openni_launch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch) for calibrating the Kinect, but when I launch the dynamic_reconfigure node and check the depth registration box it stops to publish images. When I uncheck the depth registration box it starts to publish again. Any idea to fix this? Are there some problem with the kinect driver?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46066/kinect-dynamic-reconfigure-does-not-work/) by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-10-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-10-17**:
Same problem here. Is this a common bug because I see several people experiencing the same problem

**Comment by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on 2012-10-17**:
Are there any update for the node available in the ros community to fix this problem?

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-10-18**:
I don't know for now but I am looking for a solution. If you find one, could you please share it here?

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-10-22**:
Sweet! I finally got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know why but when I installed openni_launch stack from ubuntu repos using the command below,

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-openni-launch ros-fuerte-openni-camera
```

the result is the same. Hovewer, when I tried to download the stacks from the kforge, it works. (This might be a bug in the ros-fuerte-openni-launch package, I am not sure.)

I recommend you to remove packages ros-fuerte-openni-camera and ros-fuerte-openni-launch using

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-fuerte-openni-launch ros-fuerte-openni-camera
```

and download them back using

```
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/openni_launch
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/openni_camera
```

These stacks are working for me.

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2012-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on 2012-10-24**:
Thank you very much it works also for me, maybe in these releases they have fixed the bug